# Creating a custom loading bar with rounded edges

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'd like to create a simple, custom loading bar that consists of two images I have: one image for the solid colored background and one image for the diagonals.  I'm new to iOS, so my approach is going to be to create a custom UIView that uses two UIImageViews, one for each image, with an animation block to move the diagonals image from left to right.

I'm taking this approach because I'm already familiar with UIImageViews and animation blocks.  My questions are...

1. Would you suggest a better approach?  I'm not at all familiar with layers and, due to time constraints, would prefer not to have to read up on them now, but I'm willing to if it will provide a vastly better implementation.
2. How can I "round" the ends of the loading bar?  With my current approach, this is what I'm going to get...

[image]

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: How about creating the image in another editor like photoshop, and have one UIImageView instead of trying to combine two at runtime?

Comment: i need two images to animate the diagonals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your 'solid colored background' view be a container view for the 'diagonals' imageView.
(diagonals is a subview of background)

Then set 'clipsToBounds' = YES on the diagonals subview and re-adjust the frame as necessary.  (Assuming your diagonals imageView represents 100% progress)

If your loading bar imageView doesn't have rounded corners you can just use CALayer's cornerRadius property.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [WNProgressView](https://github.com/n8chur/WNProgressView), it might do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following two ways:

1- import this class into your code  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

then add the following two lines into `-(void)viewDidLoad` method so the bar will be rounded when the view is loaded or you can add it at the place that you want the bar start to be rounded at it.

```
barImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
barImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

2- Another way is using the following code:

```
-(void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)rectCorner forView:(UIView*)view
{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds 
                                                   byRoundingCorners:rectCorner
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    
    // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

add the following line and viewDidLoad or where you want to start rounding the bar

```
[self roundCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight|UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight|UIRectCornerBottomLeft forView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] withAngle:10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Being new to iOS, you might be better off using the UIProgressView.  It might not look as nice, but it serves the same purpose and will be much easier.  There is also the UIActivityIndicatorView which is the circle which rotates like a gear.  Both are easier to use than a custom solution.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html

Comment: unfortunately the custom appearance is a necessity